# VS2008 C# OracleCommand not using parameter ending with 00

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-ce

The code issue is in a WinCE application written in VS2008 using CoreLab with an Oracle SQL backend. The details are as follows :
A 20 digit number is added to a parameter list to be used in the execution of a procedure. If the number ends in 00 the printout from the procedure indicates that the value never reached the procedure, though it works correctly in other cases.

Below is the code which adds the parameters and executes the procedure :

```
public static List<OracleParameter> ExecProc(string proc, List<OracleParameter> parameters, OracleConnection conn)
{
    if (conn == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to connect");
    }

    if (proc == null || proc == "")
    {
        throw new Exception("Procedure name cannot be blank");
    }

    CheckConnState(conn);

    List<OracleParameter> paramOutList = new List<OracleParameter>();
    OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand();
    com.Connection = conn;
    OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

    com.CommandTimeout = 0;
    com.CommandText = proc;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    foreach (OracleParameter param in parameters)
    {
        com.Parameters.Add(param.ParameterName, param.OracleDbType).Value = param.Value;
        com.Parameters[param.ParameterName].Direction = param.Direction;
        if (param.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
        {
            paramOutList.Add(com.Parameters[param.ParameterName]);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Set the output parameter values for use outside
        if (paramOutList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (OracleParameter p in paramOutList)
            {
                p.Value = com.Parameters[p.ParameterName].Value;

                //Check if there are errors and either rollback or commit. We can't leave the transaction open
                if (p.ParameterName.IndexOf("error") > 0)
                {
                    if (p.Value.ToString() != null && p.Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        trans.Rollback();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        trans.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            trans.Commit();
        }
        return paramOutList;
    }
    catch
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        return paramOutList;
    }
}
```

Edit :
Below is the sample code which calls the aforementioned method.

```
List<OracleParameter> paramList = new List<OracleParameter>
{
    GenericLib.AddParam("pn_id", OracleDbType.Number, iLongId),
    GenericLib.AddParam("pn_indicator", OracleDbType.Number, iInd),
    GenericLib.AddParam("pn_user_id", OracleDbType.Number, iUserId),
    GenericLib.AddParam("pv_in_code", OracleDbType.VarChar, null, ParameterDirection.Output),
    GenericLib.AddParam("pv_out_code", OracleDbType.VarChar, null, ParameterDirection.Output),
    GenericLib.AddParam("pv_error_code", OracleDbType.VarChar, null, ParameterDirection.Output)
};

List<OracleParameter> output = GenericLib.ExecProc("sample_procedure", paramList, conn);
```

From what I can see the first parameter never reaches the database layer as I did a printout on the first line in the proc.

Comment: Can you show us how you call this method, i.e sample procedure and list of parameters.